# link between prepareForSegue and action button

Tags: objective-c, xcode5.1

Can prepareForSegue method be applied in an action button?

If yes please can anyone teach me how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't call prepareForSegue yourself.

You create an action for your button, then call the performSegue:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier" sender:self];
```

Then in the prepareForSegue you do what you want based on the identifier.